# Cucumber Report not getting generated

Tags: maven, cucumber-java

Below is my cucumber options I am using in my test Runner class
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features", glue = "com.appname.qa.step.definitions", monochrome = true, dryRun = true, plugin = {
 "html:target/LoginReport" })

But after execution, feature files are getting executed fine but there are no report getting generated at the mentioned location. Could you please explain what could be the reason?

Also, have added below reporting dependency in pom file for cucumber

Answer (score 0):

Afaik `dryRun = true` means that it will do a dry-run (checking the syntax of your feature files, but not actually running your tests). Please remove this setting from your `@CucumberOptions` (default value is `false`) and try again.